# Applying Bayesian Statistics to Determine Probability of Improved Process

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, bayesian, inference

I am new to Bayesian Statistics but from my basic knowledge, I feel there may be real practical benefit in using it at work.

My role is to find process improvements during fabrication to improve batch yield.

An example scenario would be that I have a baseline dataset of 10000 batch yields and a second smaller experimental dataset of 100 batch yields run with a new fabrication process. Assume all the batches are the same size.

What would be the practical steps I could apply Bayesian Statistics to determine a set of probabilities that the new fabrication process improves average batch yield by X amount?